# std::swap with two double variables leads to g++ compiler error

Tags: c++, g++, std, swap

For unknown reasons, a simple std::swap leads to a compiler error:

```cpp
export module BoundingBox;

import Vector3d;
... (custom files)
import <list>;
import <string>;
import <cassert>;
import <numbers>;
import <algorithm>;
import <cstddef>;
using std::swap;
using std::iterator;
using std::list;
using std::string;
using std::numbers::pi;

export class BoundingBox {

void test()
{
        double a=1, b=2;
        std::swap(a,b);
}

};
...
```

This leads to the compiler error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/string:40,
of module /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/string, imported at raytracer/BoundingBox.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = double; std::_Require<std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<_Tp> >, std::is_move_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_move_assignable<_Tp> > = void]’:
raytracer/BoundingBox.cpp:1503239:18:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h:204:19: internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:16621
  204 |       _Tp __tmp = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__a);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
0xe4c988 internal_error(char const*, ...)
    ???:0
0xe42d02 fancy_abort(char const*, int, char const*)
    ???:0
0x1140ae0 tsubst_copy_and_build(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool, bool)
    ???:0
0x1141098 tsubst_copy_and_build(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool, bool)
    ???:0
0x1140f06 tsubst_copy_and_build(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool, bool)
    ???:0
0x11f00ff tsubst_expr(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool)
    ???:0
0x11f049b tsubst_expr(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool)
    ???:0
0x11f01de tsubst_expr(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool)
    ???:0
0x11f0174 tsubst_expr(tree_node*, tree_node*, int, tree_node*, bool)
    ???:0
0x1294a36 instantiate_decl(tree_node*, bool, bool)
    ???:0
0xfe2243 instantiate_pending_templates(int)
    ???:0
0xfddab7 c_parse_final_cleanups()
    ???:0
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to generate a minimum working example, as the error never occurs in my test cases. However I am not experienced with C++ and have no idea on where I should even be looking in the giant codebase. What could be causing this?
I use g++ 11.2.0 and compile as follows:

```
g++ -c -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header  -std=c++20 iostream algorithm numbers string vector cmath list cassert fstream cstddef
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -lGL -lglut -c \
raytracer/Vector3d.cpp \
...
raytracer/BoundingBox.cpp
...
```

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? There seems to were problems with that function: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92948

Comment: It's a bug in the compiler, follow the instructions in the error message and file a bug report

Comment: @gerum: I am using gcc 11.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by compiling `utility` as well:

```
g++ -c -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header  -std=c++20 iostream algorithm numbers string vector cmath list cassert fstream cstddef utility
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -lGL -lglut -c \
raytracer/Vector3d.cpp \
...
raytracer/BoundingBox.cpp
...
```

The strange thing is, after switching out `import <algorithm>` for `import <utility>`, it works even if I switch it back to algorithm or remove both.